# boost::interprocess How to find a container with data in shared memory in another process

Tags: c++, boost

I am learning about boost::interprocess. The examples shown in the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.allocator_introduction) describe two ways how one can create containers in shared memory: Either by constructing it completely in shared memory using `myManagedSharedMemSegement.construct<..>(..)(..)` or by creating the container in local memory with a custom allocator which puts the internal data in shared memory. As illustrated in the examples this strings data will live in shared memory, but the string itself not:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<char, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
      CharAllocator;
typedef basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator>
      MyShmString;

managed_shared_memory shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 10000);

CharAllocator charallocator  (shm.get_segment_manager());

MyShmString mystring(charallocator);
mystring = "this is my text";
```

What I could not figure out so far is how to create a string object in another process using this strings data from shared memory. Is there a reasonable way to do this or is it recommended to put the whole container in shared memory?

Comment: What you are basically doing is create your own 'shared' heap. You'll have to include the administration of the heap. I haven't done so using (boost) allocators before, my prior experience was using C-style APIs so I'd basically just treat the whole thing as a `char*` and created my own layout inside it. I'm interested to know what the modern C++ buffs have converged upon (the existence of this Boost library proves that it will have been used)

Comment: @sehe I just thought about putting C strings in shared mem and managed the mem layout myself. However I thought this may gets complicated if you need to have more things in shared memory.